# how to get `jQuery` as a function (not as a Module symbol) after ES6 style `import * as jQuery from "./js/jquery.js";`

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, es6-modules

I'm experimenting with **native ES6 modules** support in Chrome.
jQuery is not es6 module (no export) - I know. Still, trying to understand what does it mean for us.

This works without errors:

```
 <script type="module">
        import * as jQuery from "./js/jquery.js";
        window.console.log(jQuery);
 </script>
```

But of course `jQuery` thereis not a function but a `Module` symbol. 
The question is: is it possible to extract  jQuery/$ function from  jQuery module? When there are no exports defined on module?

So do we have a method to extract not exported function from Module in Chrome (as we have it e.g. in browserfy)?

P.S.  I have made an stupid error ("as jQuery" <-> "as jQyery") but it changes nothing, it is only alias name.

Comment: I've never heard of jQyery :P

Comment: Short answer: _No_. Long answer: _Please allow me ask you this: why?_ .

Comment: @KarelG thank you for your answer, but please do not use such freaky rhetoric. If you know long answer please tell it. If you want to ask why I'm trying this:
Because native es6 modules loading works well only when all modules are loaded using es6 module system. jquery is just a sample there could be other e.g. popper.js. Scripts you load with plain `script src` is not seem as modules - so on `import * as` they will be loaded twice. I'm trying to avoid this loading them as modules as well. Something like `import * as jQuery from "./js/jquery.js";
            window.$ = jQuery;`

Comment: your long answer should include explanation "why in browserify this is possible" and what prevents do the same in native support.

Comment: Nothing stops you to `import("...")` (without `from`) only because of its side effects and then write your own module with `export default jQuery` but Kerel is right: what for? What are you trying to accomplish with this?

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti thank you for your answer. import(..) will return promise that return module again, not function, could you explain how to get function?

Here I'm just investigating. I have answered to KarelG where I see the problem. I you need to load module both using `script src` and  as `module` that means you will load it twice. I'm trying to avoid it, by trying various tricks. Other aspect: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51921815/how-to-make-script-loading-and-es6-module-loading-working-together

Comment: If you're inside a module and you write `import ".lib/jquery"` (sorry, in my previous comment I used the `()` syntax for the promise) you now have a `jQuery` function (created only because of the side effects of the module) which you can export. Something roughly like `import "/libs/jQuery"; export default jQuery;`

Comment: About your other question...AFAIK that's not possible but I never had to; it makes sense and maybe someone found a workaround.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti THANK YOU. You return me for the SO community since I've started thinking that I lost the wave. And your suggested import works. it is so simple. Please - create an answer!

Comment: @RomanPokrovskij you welcome, but to write a decent answer we should discuss about the reason you need it and possibly merge it with your other (interesting) question. I'm waaaaaay too lazy! :)

Comment: I can't believe that you are serious. There are no reson to expain "why" asking the question" is it possible to import jquery (export free js) through native es6 modules support"? Because I want to use es6 modules specific (e.g. import only once). It is obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
 <script type="module">
        import "./js/jquery.js";
        window.console.log(window.$);
 </script>
```

creates jQuery on window as "side effect". JQuery code

```
( function( global, factory ) {
    "use strict";
    if (typeof module === "object" && typeof module.exports === "object") {
      // ...
    } else {
        // we are there when loading as ES6 native module
        factory( global );
    }

} )( typeof window !== "undefined" ? window : this, function( window, noGlobal ) { 
   // ... jquery code
});
```

There is some specific in this and the same behaviour can't be expected from all "legacy" scripts.

What is interesting next also works (my explaination: because of "fetching first rule")

```
 <script type="module">
        window.console.log(window.$); // also works and will return $ function even if import is declared bellow
        import "./js/jquery.js";
 </script>
```

Syntax `import "module-name"` described there 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

Google article: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/modules

Also this loads jquery ONLY ONCE (and execute it ONLY ONCE):

```
    <script type="module">
        import("./js/jquery.js").then(
           function(){
               window.console.log("inline 2a =  " + window.$);
           }
        );
    </script>

    <script type="module">
         import("./js/jquery.js").then(
           function(){
               window.console.log("inline 2b =  " + window.$);
           }
        );
    </script>
```

This is important feature that can be used in development.

P.S.

This works also but has its trap:

```
 <script type="module">
 import * as jQuery from "./js/jquery.js"
            window.console.log(jQuery); // returns Module
            window.console.log(window.jQuery); // returns jQuery function
 </script type="module">
```